# Building Sqlite3 with R*Tree on OSX

Tags: sqlite, makefile

I am trying to build SQLite with R*tree module on OSX. Here are some relevant parts of my makefile

```
CFLAGS= -O1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE=1
SFLAGS= -ldl -lpthread 
##############################################################################
%.o: %.c
    gcc -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

#Building SQLite3 shell for administrative purposes
shell : shell.c sqlite3.o
    gcc $(SFLAGS) -o shell.out shell.c sqlite3.o
```

However, the R*Tree is still not available. I do have a copy of sqlite3 installed using homebrew and R*Tree works fine on that. However, I am not sure what is wrong when I build the amalgamation myself.

Comment: Are you actually using that copy of SQLite?

Comment: Yes. I am using the binary generated in the local directory.

Comment: You should use `CFLAGS` in both `gcc` calls (but this should not matter for the  R-tree module). What is the output of `pragma compile_options;`?

Comment: I get : SYSTEM_MALLOC
THREADSAFE=1. "ENABLE_RTREE" is missing.

Comment: I solved the problem by downloading the latest version of amalgamation from the website and replacing the files in my project directory.